# bootstrap 5 tooltip does not hide after clicking

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, tooltip, bootstrap-5

i am using bootstrap 5 in my project and i'm trying to use tooltip but there is a problem;
when i trigger mouse enter and mouse leave events everything work well but when i click on specified element the tooltip display and after that it doesn't hide.

this is my element

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="جزئیات" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" type="button"><i class="bi bi-eye-fill m-0"></i></button>
```

and this is how i initial tooltip

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')).map((tooltipTriggerEl) => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
```

when i click on this button, a model should display. I think these should be related

please look at this image

[image]

```
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
       container: 'body',
       trigger : 'hover'
   });
 })
```

i know this is because of displaying model. please help

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @GauriKesavaKumar You can close them manually. find class of popups and close them after firing an event

Comment: try with container attribute and set modal id. `$('.tooltips').tooltip({animation: true, container: '#modalID', html: true, placement: 'auto', trigger: 'hover'});`